# Creating figures from matlab for use in latex (problem: activating legend changes figure size)

Tags: graphics, plot, eps, matlab

At the moment I am creating a lot of figures while writing my PhD thesis. As I am using a lot of Matlab I use the function `matlabfrag` to export my figure to LaTeX:

**MATLAB**

```
h = figure(1);
plot(rand(10),rand(10));
legend(random);
grid on

set(gcf,'defaulttextinterpreter','latex');

set(gca,'FontSize',font_axes); 

ht = get(gca,'Title');    
set(ht,'FontSize',font_title);

hx = get(gca,'XLabel');                         
set(hx,'FontSize',font_xy);

hy = get(gca,'YLabel');                         
set(hy,'FontSize',font_xy);

hl = findobj(gcf,'Type','axes','Tag','legend'); 
set(hl,'FontSize',font_legend);
set(hl,'Location','northeast');

xlabel(x_text,'FontSize',font_xy);
ylabel(y_text,'FontSize',font_xy);

set(gcf,'Units','inches')

set(gcf,'PaperPositionMode','auto')

set(h,'Position',[1 1 1+width 1+height]);

set(gca, 'Position', get(gca, 'OuterPosition') - ...
get(gca, 'TightInset') * [-1 0 1 0; 0 -1 0 1; 0 0 1 0; 0 0 0 1]);

matlabfrag(test);

saveas(h,figure_name,'fig')
```

**LaTeX**

```
\begin{figure}[ht] 
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
       \centering
       \psfragfig[frame]{test}
       \caption[short caption]{caption} 
             \label{fig:21}
    \end{minipage} \end{figure}
```

This gives me a nice result. But now the problem is, while activating and deactivating the legend I obtain different figure sizes:

[image]

To be exactly, the figure size is the same, but the pictures seem to be cropped differently.

I know this is half a matlab problem. But I think a lot of people who use latex encouter this function in order to get nice latex plots for their thesis.

Hopefully someone can help me with this strange problem? As I plot a lot of figures on top of a new page these different heights of the figures are a big problem as the following text on a left and on a right handed page will not be on the same line.

Thanks in advance for your help! Also if someone knows an easier solution this would be really cool.

Comment: I recommend the use of Matlab2tikz (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz) instead. It involves a bit of work at the beginning but you have full control and you can compile with pdflatex.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. As I already did a lot of work for matlabfrag I would really prefer using it. I am not quite sure anymore if my problem is still a 'more Latex' problem, so I asked for help in a matlab forum: http://www.gomatlab.de/viewtopic,p,167489.html#167489